# ¿Cómo ejecuto una función interna al efectuar un pago en X pasarela de pagos?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe

Estoy trabajando con Firebase con una plataforma de cursos e intento añadir la pasarela de pagos **"Stripe"**.
En resúmen yo me estoy trayendo los cursos con toda su info a través de una API creada en firebase, al leer la entrada de cada curso tengo la información del respectivo curso y dentro, un botón de "Añadir al carrito". Cuando el usuario presiona en "Añadir al carrito", (valga la redundancia) añade al carrito el objeto completo del curso. En la página de carrito al tocar "Finalizar compra", setea todos los objetos en el documento de firebase "misCursos" y el usuario ya tiene en la página "Mis cursos" todos los cursos.

Lo que yo quiero lograr es que al tocar "Finalizar compra", pase por la pasarela de pagos **Stripe** y cuando esta compra sea exitosa, recién que se efectúe la función que te añade el curso a "misCursos" de firebase.
¿Cómo podría lograr algo así? Estuve investigando y Stripe tiene una sección "Productos" y los creas desde ahí, pero en mi caso los tengo en la API de firebase. Muchas gracias por su tiempo.

Esta es la función que quiero que se ejecute cuando la compra ya esté finalizada.

```
  async function agregarMisCursos(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Comprando...");

    if (!usuario) {
      return router.push("/login");
    }

    try {
      if (carrito.length === 0) {
        alert("No puedes comprar con el carrito vacío.");
      } else {
        await addDoc(collection(firebase.db, "misCursos"), carritoObjeto);
        vaciarCarrito();
      }

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

PD: si existe otra pasarela de pagos similar a Stripe también me sirve.

Comment: ¿te refieres a esto?: https://extensions.dev/extensions/stripe/firestore-stripe-payments

Comment: Exacto, esa es una opción. Lo único que necesito es que al comprar el producto se ejecute esa función

Comment: ¿y has seguido el tutorial? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L_ADtp1tWPA

Comment: Tu pregunta es demasiado amplia. [es.so] no está pensado para darte un tutorial completo sobre como implementar una u otra librería, framework o API. Te sugiero que te dirijas a la documentación de Stripe o de cualquier pasarela de pagos y te documentes (valga la redundancia) sobre las diferentes formas de consumirlas. Saludos